# Check for duplicates before inserting into table

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a nodejs application which users can buy products . I have a mysql database and sequelize. I have an object like this:

```
 const Data = {
    TransID,
    TransTime,
    Amount: TransAmount,
    BillRefNumber,
    MSISDN,
    FirstName,
    MiddleName,
    LastName,
    ShortCode: BusinessShortCode,
  };
```

For any new transactions, I would like to check, using the TransId, whether this transaction exists in my table using the TransId . What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Probably best to set up the table to not allow duplicates and then just try the insert and see an error and deal with that error if its a duplicate.  If you check first to see if its there (in any non-atomic way), then you open it up for a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of the best ways is to add a unique attribute to the TransID field in the database table. When you insert it, add a try-catch. It will catch an error if the same TransID already exists in the database. All you have to do is display the error.

Comment: Yes I agree . This would be the best way, adding a unique attribute to that field. But suppose this app is in production, and the only way to add a unique field is to first remove the duplicates in the table(which I would not like to do) .